# A doubt about Yang-Mills equation in trivial $U(1)$-bundles

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, yang-mills

I know that the Yang-Mills equation is $\delta F=0$ where $\delta$ is the adjoint operator of the covariant derivative and $F$ is the curvature of a principal connection. In a trivial $U(1)$-bundle (for example $\mathbb{R}^4\times U(1)$ as the one used in electrodynamics), $F=dA$ for some 1-form $A$, so the Yang-Mills equation is $\delta dA=0$, but considering the inner product $\langle-,-\rangle$ we have for all 1-form $B$ $$0=\langle B,\delta F\rangle=\langle B,\delta dA\rangle=\langle dB,dA\rangle$$ in particular for $B=A$, so $$0=\langle dA,dA\rangle \Longrightarrow 0=dA=F,$$ i.e., if a connection satisfies the Yang-Mills equation then its curvature is zero. But if this is correct, in $\mathbb{R}^4\times U(1)$ we have that the electromagnetic field is always zero (F=0) which is clearly wrong. What is going on?? I can't see it!! Is this apparent contradiction because in $\mathbb{R}^4$, $\langle-,-\rangle$ is not defined for all 1-forms?? or because it is not an inner product (taking the Minkowski metric)??

Comment: The E&M equation of motion is $d \star F = J$, so in vacuum $d \star F = 0$. If you got a different result then there must be a mistake somewhere. I'm not seeing the Hodge star $\star$ in what you've written here.

Comment: @user1379857 the Hodge star is implicit in the co-differential: $\delta\sim\star d\star$

Comment: @user1379857 I  know, but I can't see it. My problem is not the equation of motion, my problem is that apparently, just F=0 satisfies the equation of motion, which is wrong but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

How does $\int_M F \wedge \star F = 0$ imply that $F = 0$? $\int_M F \wedge \star F $ corresponds to the Lagrangian of the field, which is the integral of $E^2 - B^2$. That can be $0$ even if $F$ isn't $0$. This is actually satisfied for a plane wave of light.

In Lorentzian signature, the inner product $\int_M (\cdot) \wedge \star (\cdot)$ is not positive definite, so the fact that its zero doesn't mean the input is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in fact contained in the last line of the question: the reason is that it is not an inner product (taking the Minkowski metric). If we were studying Yang-Mills theory in a *Euclidean* space (with appropriate boundary conditions), then indeed F=0 would be the only solution (waves exist only for indefinite metric)

Answer (score 1):

The bundle $\mathbb{R}^4\times U(1)$ is trivial, and thus admits a flat connection $A$, namely the Maurer-Cartan form $g^{-1}dg$. The fact that this is flat, just means that $dA=0$, and this is certainly a solution to the Yang-Mills equations in a vacuum. However, it is a trivial solution, and we are, in general, interested in non trivial solutions.

What you are saying is like looking at the Maxwell field equations in a vacuum, and then concluding that $E=B=0$, which is certainly a solution to that set of PDE's, but it is not the only solution, and is indeed a trivial solution.

Edit:

Furthermore, your inner product is really:

\begin{align*}
\langle \omega,\eta\rangle_{L^2}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}\langle \omega,\eta\rangle\text{dvol}_g
\end{align*}
where:
\begin{align*}
\langle \omega,\eta\rangle=\frac{1}{k!}\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}\eta^{i_1\cdots i_k}
\end{align*}
and $\text{dvol}_g$ is your volume form. For general pseudo-Riemannian metrics, this inner product does not satisfy:
\begin{align*}
\langle \omega,\omega\rangle_{L^2}\geq 0
\end{align*}
It is however non-degenerate, meaning that if:
\begin{align*}
\langle \omega,\eta\rangle_{L^2}=0
\end{align*}
for all $\eta$, then $\omega=0$. In your case, we have that $\delta dA=0$, so your reasoning that:
\begin{align*}
\langle A,\delta dA \rangle_{L^2}=0\Rightarrow \langle dA, dA \rangle_{L^2}=0
\end{align*}
is correct. However, you have not shown that $\langle dA,\omega\rangle_{L^2}=0$ for all $\omega\in \Omega^2(M)$. You have shown that for all exact $2$ forms, i.e. those that can be written as $dB$, that the $L^2$ inner product is zero, but this is simply not the case in general.